# OpenLayers3 map.forEachLayerAtPixel bug

Tags: openlayers, pixel

Hi I'm working with OpenLayers version 3 and using method map.forEachLayerAtPixel(). The problem is I usually work on big screen and now I have switched to my laptop with smaller one and suddenly function is not working at certain zoom levels. I have to zoom at max and only then it works. Does someone encountered this problem maybe ? The same method when working with OpenLayers5 works properly..

Comment: There was a problem in version 3, it seems to have been fixed in first release of version 4 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6250

Comment: @Mike do you know is there some workaround in this case , because I already have my app written in OL3 . I would have to rewrite whole application.

Comment: In the later releases of version 3 you could try setting `pixelRatio: 1` in the map options